# Show Images that are coded with HSV in real colors with PIL or Opencv

Tags: python, opencv, rgb, hsv

I have converted an image with opencv to hsv with the code:

```
hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

Now I look at the Image with PIL using

```
Image.fromarray(np.asarray(hsv_img,dtype=np.uint8))
```

The now showed image is now the interpretation of the HSV values as RGBs. Is it possible to display the Image from the HSV color spectrum interpreted as HSV and not as RGBs without changing it back to RGB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
Image.fromarray(np.asarray(hsv_img,dtype=np.uint8))
```

to include mode, so:

```
Image.fromarray(np.asarray(hsv_img ,dtype=np.uint8), 'HSV')
```

PIL's show() method should then display that correctly.